# Understanding a formula on acceleration

Tags: vector-spaces, classical-mechanics

We are given the formula in vectors, $\underline{a}=(μ\underline{r} \times \underline{v})/r^3$ where "$\underline{a}$" is the acceleration of any particle, "$\underline{r}$" is the displacement and "$\underline{v}$" is the velocity and "$μ$" hasn't defined and "$\times$" is the cross product in vectors. Then we are supposed to proceed the lesson. I want to know 
how this formula developed.
Can somebody explain this please?

Comment: I have to say I've never seen that formula in my career as a physics grad student...and unless mu is in units of $ m^3 $ it wouldn't yield acceleration

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not very clear as to where this equation comes from. Is it just an example problem and you are wondering what would produce such a physics?

( One circumstance where a force like this could occur is in the case of a particle moving in a magnetic field. In particular, consider a "magnetic charge" at the origin producing a field $ B \propto \frac{\hat{r}}{r^2} $, then the force $ F = q v \times B $ will give a formula similar to the problem with the appropriate constant $ \mu $. )

Comment: That's one thing I suspected but was hesitant to say

Comment: We are given this formula under the topic of "acceleration of an object" at a class lecture and then using this we are supposed to show that particle has a constant speed and it's angular momentum has two components such that one is a constant vector and the other is a constant vector in the opposite direction of r_ at a tutorial. I showed the questions but I want to know the idea of the formula.